# Voltage and current during the first cycle of RL circuit

Tags: ac, inductor, transient

I have a simulation of RL circuit connected with an ac source. Any one can tell me please that why the peak of the current during the first positive half cycle is higher than the peak of current during the  first negative half cycle although both halves of the cycle come from the same voltage source and current goes through the same components in both positive and negative half cycles?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not limited to inductors. It happens with capacitors when driven with a sinusoidal current that begins at a phase angle of 0°: -

[image]

It quite literally is *the process of mathematical integration* at work.

If you integrate a sinewave that begins at t=0 then you will get the same effect.

**It's math and, inductors and capacitors do math; they integrate.**

There is no circuit trick; if you mathematically integrated a sinewave that starts from 0° you will get a waveform that is a bit top-heavy and gradually settles in time due to the presence of the resistor.

Comment: Agreed. If we connect and ideal current source with an ideal capacitor then the voltage that was built by the positive current will be canceled out by the voltage built by the negative current. But yet I do not understand that why adding a resistor will make the voltage go negative in this case and why the resistor will make the current go negative in RL circuit. I know that the resistor burn the energy isn't it true that the energy burnt by the resistor for both the half cycles is same?

Comment: *If we connect and ideal current source with an ideal capacitor then the voltage that was built by the positive current will be cancelled out by the voltage built by the negative current.* - no it won't when the sinewave begins at t = 0. There is no cancellation; it is integration and not cancellation @Alex

Comment: So isn't the current supplied during the positive half cycle is equal to the current supplied during the negative half cycle in an RL circuit and isn't that make the peak of the current same for both positive and negative half cycle ?

Comment: No it's not the same current @Alex - clearly it's not else the graph wouldn't show what you are asking about.

Comment: For the positive half cycle of the current voltage rises and for the negative half cycle of current the voltage falls back to zero. I called it cancelation.

Comment: Yes that's what I want to know that why it's not same because of resistor?

Comment: If you shorted the resistor in the RL circuit, the current would never go negative so, it's not the resistor that causes the asymmetry but the process of integration. It's not cancellation; it's integration in every sense of the word both mathematically and in engineering terms.

Comment: Haaa? What's the difference between cancelation and integration in this regard? And isn't it after adding resistors that the current go negative? So isn't the resistor responsible? When inductor was alone he never let go current negative. So resistor is not responsible?

Comment: The natural state of affairs after a long length of time is for the waveform to lose the transient and become symmetrical about 0 volts. The resistor ensures this. The resistor is responsible for allowing the transient to settle. Without the resistor there is a permanent transient and the current never settles.

Comment: Yes that's what I need to know that how adding resistor settles the transient? I need an intuitive answer of that. What magic does resistor do. Yes they burn energy but energy they burn is same for the both half cycles. So how they cause the peak of current to become less during the negative half cycle in RL circuit?

Comment: The resistor will burn more energy in a half cycle that is bigger than a half cycle that is smaller hence, it will equalize half cycles to the same amplitude in the fullness of time.

Comment: Oh you mean to say that resistor burn more energy during the positive half cycle of voltage than the negative half cycle of voltage in RL circuit?

Comment: But both half cycles of voltage source are equal but opposite. Isn't it? Then how come the peak of current during the positive half cycle of voltage will be more than the current during the negative half cycle?

Comment: It's quite simply this; if you begin a sinewave at an abrupt point (even if it's zero degrees), then the first half cycle (positive) will accumulate a bigger peak value through the process of integration. If you began the waveform at 90 degrees then it won't; look at the area under the sinewave.

Comment: "It's quite simply this; if you begin a sinewave at an abrupt point (even if it's zero degrees), then the first half cycle (positive) will accumulate a bigger peak value through the process of integration." and then what will happen during the negative half cycle? Voltage is same resistance and inductance is same. Then will the negative half cycle of voltage will integrate the peak of the current back to zero before the negative half cycle is complete? And this will happen because of the resistance?

Comment: Because the first half cycle accumulates a larger than normal peak value, the first negative cycle has to integrate down from that transient positive high point and there isn't enough area under the curve (a la integration) to take it all the way to the negative value it achieves in the fullness of time.

Comment: The next positive half cycle starts with a current that is partially full negative and hence it gets closer in the 2nd cycle and even closer in the third cycle etc.. In the first half positive cycle if you look, the current begins at zero hence it produces the biggest positive value in current.

Comment: I understand now @Andy aka. I love you.

Comment: @Alex don't be so soppy LOL

Answer (score 3):

Well, using Laplace transform we can see that:

$$\text{I}_\text{in}\left(t\right)=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\hat{\text{u}}\omega}{\text{s}^2+\omega^2}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{R}+\text{sL}}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\tag1$$

Using the convolution property of the Laplace transform, we can write:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_\text{in}\left(t\right)&=\int\limits_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\hat{\text{u}}\omega}{\text{s}^2+\omega^2}\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\text{R}+\text{sL}}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\int\limits_0^t\hat{\text{u}}\sin\left(\omega\tau\right)\cdot\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{\text{R}}{\text{L}}\cdot\left(t-\tau\right)\right)}{\text{L}}\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{L}}\int\limits_0^t\sin\left(\omega\tau\right)\exp\left(-\frac{\text{R}}{\text{L}}\cdot\left(t-\tau\right)\right)\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}\cdot\left(\omega\text{L}\left(\exp\left(-\frac{\text{R}t}{\text{L}}\right)-\cos\left(\omega t\right)\right)+\text{R}\sin\left(\omega t\right)\right)
\end{alignat*}
\tag2
$$

And, when we have:

$$\text{I}_\text{in}\left(t\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}\cdot\left(\omega\text{L}\left(\underbrace{\exp\left(-\frac{\text{R}t}{\text{L}}\right)}_{=\space\text{K}\left(t\right)}-\cos\left(\omega t\right)\right)+\text{R}\sin\left(\omega t\right)\right)\tag3$$

We, can see that when \$t\to\infty\$ we have \$\text{K}\left(t\right)=0\$. So, without the transient part we get:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\overline{\text{I}}_\text{in}\left(t\right)&=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}\cdot\left(\omega\text{L}\left(0-\cos\left(\omega t\right)\right)+\text{R}\sin\left(\omega t\right)\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}\left(\text{R}\sin\left(\omega t\right)-\omega\text{L}\cos\left(\omega t\right)\right)}{\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}
\end{alignat*}
\tag4
$$

The amplitude of the resulting current is given by:

$$\hat{\overline{\text{I}}_\text{in}}=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\sqrt{\text{R}^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}}\tag5$$

Answer (score 0):

Read this question and my answer:

[Transients in series RL circuit with AC source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/558561/transients-in-series-rl-circuit-with-ac-source/558583#558583)

It's the transient term of the current that adds up to the steady state term of the current.